# How to implement if-else statement for every cell in transposed dataframe using Python

Tags: pandas, if-statement

I'm new to Python
I have no idea how to incorporate if-else statement for every data after transposing .csv raw file using Pandas.

My transposed data using Pandas:

```
Voltage 0.2V 0.4V 0.6V 0.8V 1V 1.2V
Point A 0 15 100 5000 300 50
Point B 10000 4000 500 10 0 0
Point C 0 10 40 200 400 1000
```

Intended conditional statement inside every data of Point A, B & C

```
    If (data = 0){
    State = 0;
    }
    elsif (data >0 and data <= 10){
    State = 1;
    }
    elsif (data >10 and data <= 100){
    State = 2;
    }
    elsif (data >100 and data <= 1000){
    State = 3;
    }
    elsif (data >1000 and data <= 10000){
    State = 4;
    }
    else {
    State = "Invalid";
    }
```

My Expected output:

```
Voltage 0.2V 0.4V 0.6V 0.8V 1V 1.2V
Point A 0 2 2 4 3 2
Point B 4 4 3 1 0 0
Point C 0 1 2 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with converted DataFrame for Series by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), add missing category by [`cat.add_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html) and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (df)
   Voltage    0.2V  0.4V  0.6V  0.8V   1V  1.2V
0  Point A  100000    15   100  5000  300    50 <-changed first value for invalid
1  Point B   10000  4000   500    10    0     0
2  Point C       0    10    40   200  400  1000

df = df.set_index('Voltage')
s = pd.cut(df.stack(),
            bins=[-np.inf, 0,10,100,1000,10000], 
            labels=[0, 1,2,3,4], 
            right=True)
s = s.cat.add_categories(['Invalid'])
df1 = s.unstack().fillna('Invalid')
print (df1)
            0.2V 0.4V 0.6V 0.8V 1V 1.2V
Voltage                                
Point A  Invalid    2    2    4  3    2
Point B        4    4    3    1  0    0
Point C        0    1    2    3  3    3
```